# Pushing locally saved projects into an existing subgroup in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I cloned a number (around 20)of projects from an external gitlab account. I have them now locally and I want to push all of them into a subgroup I created for them in my gitlab account. Is there an easy way of doing it?